# Manually positioning ticks on axis - D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a graph using d3 and I wanted to put the ticks on my xAxis at positions which I would specify. For example if I wanted the ticks at the following positions,[-11,0,11,18,30,42], how would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the documentation -- [`axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/v1.0.12/README.md#axis_tickValues).

Comment: Thanks so much. I didnt see that when going through he API docs

Comment: Do you know how to make it where you specify the position of the ticks, and then give it names? for example, if I want the ticks to be at position ,[-11,0,11,18,30,42] but with labels [11,0,11,12,0,12] how would I do that? Sorry for not adding this in the original question.

Comment: The `axis.tickFormat()` function (same page further down) is your friend.

Comment: That link is no longer good, for d3 v3, you are looking for [this page](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Axes.md)