# D3.js - how to draw grid lines for specific axis ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gridlines

I am trying to draw some line charts using D3.js. I found some codes like http://jsfiddle.net/BDWFW/.

```
var w = 760;
var h = 400;
var pad = 50;
var d0 = new Date("Jan 29 2011 UTC");
var d1 = new Date("March 15 2011 UTC");
var x = d3.time.scale()  .domain([d0, d1]).range([0,w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1])  .range([h,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("height", h + pad)
    .attr("width",  w + pad)

var vis = svg.append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,20)")

var rules = vis.append("svg:g").classed("rules", true)

function make_x_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(8)
}

function make_y_axis() {
  return d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(10)
}

rules.append("svg:g").classed("grid x_grid", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+h+")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
      .tickSize(-h,0,0)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("grid y_grid", true)
    .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSize(-w,0,0)
      .tickFormat("")
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("labels x_labels", true)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+h+")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
      .tickSize(5)
      // .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y/%m"))
    )

rules.append("svg:g").classed("labels y_labels", true)
    .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSubdivide(1)
      .tickSize(10, 5, 0)
    )
```

As we can see in the result, all grid lines are connected to every ticks. Instead, I would like to choose specific ticks and draw grid lines only for those ticks.  Unfortunately, I am not sure how I can do it with D3.js. For example, in this example, how can we make gridlines for Feb06, Feb20, and Mar06?

Sometimes, I really don't understand D3.js. Look at this gridline drawing part:

```
rules.append("svg:g").classed("grid y_grid", true)
    .call(make_y_axis()
      .tickSize(-w,0,0)
      .tickFormat("")
    )
```

I am really not sure about how this code draws a gridline. Among the chained function, I couldn't find which one doing that. Some novice users like me feel like everything is in a Blackbox.

Comment: Use `.tickValues([values])` on the axis to specify where to put ticks.

Comment: Thank you, Lars. But I don't understand it. Could you please let me know about that in more detail? I am not trying to create different ticks but trying to draw gridlines based on specific ticks.

Comment: Well the grid lines are drawn with long ticks. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297610/manually-positioning-ticks-on-axis-d3) for a bit more background.